# @Autowired entityManagerFactory is null

Tags: spring, hibernate

My app can't autowire entityManagerFactory.

My **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="top.level.package" />

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"     
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <value>classpath:jpa-persistence.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"      
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

My **java class**:

```
@Component
public class Engine {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
......
}
```

**Question:**

*Why entityManagerFactory is null?*

Comment: How do you get an instance of Engine?

Comment: Possibly because of `@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")`. You haven't qualified the emf in your xml configuration

Comment: @orid It goes by `id` attribute.

Comment: did you add @Component to Engine and add component-scan in config?

Comment: I get the instance of engine in next way:
Engine engine = new Engine();

Comment: yeah, I've @component annotation on Engine class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For spring to do autowring using annotations you have to tell spring that. In your xml configuration (assuming you don't already have `context:component-scan` element) add a `context:annotation-config`. This will instruct the spring application context to scan for annotations (like `@Autowired`, `@Inject`, `@Resource` etc.) to do autowiring.

Also make sure that the class you want the `EntityManagerFactory` to be injected into (the `Engine` class) is a spring managed bean. Spring will only inject references into spring managed beans.

Comment: I've <tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="top.level.package" />, but it doesn't work

Comment: Is your `Engine` class a spring managed bean? Or are you constructing instances yourself? Spring will only inject dependencies into beans it knows and manages.

Comment: You a right! I'm knew in spring and never ming about that fact that I create an Engine as a POJO. Please add this to your answer, and I will accept it

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with this ?

```
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Autowired
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myUnitName")
public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
}
```

I had the same error some time ago, and I found this a solution.

Comment: It does not work for me. The same result - entityManagerFactory is null

Answer (score 0):

If you craeate your `Engine` with `new Engine()` (as stated in one of your comments), it's not managed by Spring. `@Component` has no effect then and dependencies won't be injected. You need to inject your engine.